# Getting basic user data from authorised google account

Tags: java, android, mobile

In this android application, I want to get the user data (email id, name, etc) from the authorised google account. In this case I'm caching tokens to see if the user is logged in or not, and if the user is already logged in, it will fetch the basic user data.

The code uses a button to login.

```
    public void login(View view){

    if (loadUserTokenCache(mClient)){
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        ListenableFuture<MobileServiceUser> mLogin = mClient.login(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google);

        Futures.addCallback(mLogin, new FutureCallback<MobileServiceUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable exc) {
                createAndShowDialog("You must log in. Login Required", "Error");
            }
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(MobileServiceUser user) {
                createAndShowDialog(String.format(
                        "You are now logged in - %1$2s",
                        user.getUserId()), "Success");
                cacheUserToken(mClient.getCurrentUser());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the AccountsManager. For example, this is how you could retrieve the user's gmail.

```
// Retrieve the gmail associated with the device that is being used.
    String gmailID = "";
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getActivity()).getAccountsByType("com.google");
    if(accounts.length > 0) {
        gmailID = accounts[0].name;
    }
```